# Calculating change of basis matrix / operator in matrix space

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

I am aware of how to calculate the change of basis matrix when dealing with usual vectors. However, I don't know how to do it for matrices.

Let $M$ be a $2\times2$ matrix with entries $m_{ij}$. It is clear that it has components $m_{ij}$ in the following basis:
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0 \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

How can I obtain $M$ on an arbitrary basis?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Think your last matrix should be $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ yeah?

Comment: @PrimeMover Yes, I made a mistake. I will edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just choose another four $2\times2$ matrices which could be linearly independent, then write them as a linear combinations of those initial ones. Hence you can associate a $4\times4$ matrix loaded with the coefficients of the linear combinations of your choice. If the determinant of such a matrix is nonzero then your new matrices form a new basis for that space.

Comment: So it's just treating each matrix as a vector. I guess it was that simple. I will try it and then I'll accept your answer. Thank you.

Comment: you are on the true track!